# How to replace only 3rd character of employee name with * in SQL

Tags: sql

How to replace only 3rd character of employee name with * in SQL.

Comment: The answer will likely depend on the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? MySQL, SQL-Server?

Answer (score 3):

On SQL Server you can use this:

```
SELECT STUFF(N'Employee',3,1,N'*')
```

On MySQL

```
SELECT INSERT(N'Employee',3,1,N'*')
```

Answer (score 3):

ANSI SQL way:

```
SUBSTRING(employee from 1 for 2) || '*' ||  SUBSTRING(employee from 4)
```

Alternatively `PASTE` is used by some dbms products:

```
PASTE(employee,3,1,'*')
```

Comment: What databases use `paste()`?